# how to exclude js file in bundle and use it in a different chunk/bundle instead?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

I currently have a few variables in a js file and would like to put it in its own bundle outside of my main app.bundle.js.

config.js

```
export const url1= 'testing1';
export const url2= 'test2';
```

I have a very basic webpack like this and added the new entry(This is just an example)

```
module.exports = {
{
entry: {
   app: [path.resolve(__dirname, './src/index.js')],
   config: [path.resolve(__dirname, './config.js')] <---here
 },
 output: {
   filename: '[name].js',
   path: __dirname + '/built'
  }
}

module.loaders: [
 {
  // "test" is commonly used to match the file extension
   test: /\.jsx$/,

   // "include" is commonly used to match the directories
  include: [
  path.resolve(__dirname, "app/src"),
  path.resolve(__dirname, "app/test")
 ],

  // "exclude" should be used to exclude exceptions
  // try to prefer "include" when possible

  // the "loader"
  loader: "babel-loader"
  }]
```

finally I have a src/file.js that wants to use the config.js (I'm currently doing this but i am not sure if this is correct)

```
import { url1, url2} from '../../config.js';
```

my app bundle will bundle all the js files expanded from my index.js(which is all my /src .js files).
My config.js is outside of the src folder however I want one of my js files from src to use those variables that I have set in the config.js.

My result does produce a conf.bundle.js with the variables but it also seems to be bundled into the app.bundle.js as well.

So now my question is how would I be able to use the config.bundle.js variables on my app.bundle.js without having a copy of config.js in the app.bundle.js

Answer (score 0):

Adding [CommonChunksPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting-libraries/#commonschunkplugin) solves this issue.

Comment: It would be nice to explain why it solves the problem. Link only answers are cumbersome.